# Could't Import Django: Are you sure it's installed and activated in your PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, pythonpath

I am trying to run django in python 3.6.8. When using pip freeze in my activated venv i get this list:

```
asgiref==3.2.3
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.1
distlib==0.3.3
Django==3.0.8
django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus==3.0.5
django-crispy-forms==1.9.1
filelock==3.3.2
importlib-metadata==4.8.2
importlib-resources==5.4.0
mysqlclient @ file:///D:/Downloads/mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl
Pillow==7.2.0
platformdirs==2.4.0
pytz==2020.1
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.3.1
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
virtualenv==20.10.0
zipp==3.6.0
```

When i try to run my migrate.py file the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
  File "C:\Users\never\envmon\airquality\django-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from django.core.management.base import (
  File "C:\Users\never\envmon\airquality\django-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core import checks
  File "C:\Users\never\envmon\airquality\django-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import django.core.checks.caches  # NOQA isort:skip
  File "C:\Users\never\envmon\airquality\django-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\caches.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.cache import DEFAULT_CACHE_ALIAS
  File "C:\Users\never\envmon\airquality\django-venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\cache\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from asgiref.local import Local
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

The virtual environment is activated. I tried setting up the PYTHONPATH in my environment variables with no success.
I am using a windows 10 machine. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you recreate the problem from scratch, starting by making a new virtual environment?

Comment: Followed all steps from the start and it works now, thanks for the suggestion. Perhaps i needed to add django to the PYTHONPATH before making the venv.

Comment: If you can find a way to [repeatably](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) cause the problem, starting from scratch, then you might well end up with a very high quality question that you'd also be able to [answer yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).